# How to trigger bulk mode scan in zxing

Tags: android, zxing

I read there is a key to enable bulk mode scan in zxing. May I know how do i enable this key in an android application?

I am currently using such codes to scan a barcode individually:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "PRODUCT_MODE,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF");

startActivityForResult(intent, 0); // start the scan
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "bulk mode scan"?

Comment: As in once ZXing starts the camera, it can keep scanning barcodes into a list and the camera exits only when user clicks a button. This list can be stored as a csv file as mentioned by others in the forum.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can from the stock implementation. See, https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java Instead, you will have to build it into your application and modify it to do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no concept of "bulk mode" within zxing I don't think.

You can certainly implement the behavior that you are looking for though with zxing inside your own application. Use the code that you already have in your question to kick of Scanning for the first time. Add this declaration to your class:

```
ArrayList<String> results;
```

Then add this inside onCreate *before* you start scanning to initialize it:

```
results = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Inside your onActivityResult() you can add the current result to your ArrayList and then start the next scan.

```
/*Here is where we come back after the Barcode Scanner is done*/
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // contents contains whatever the code was
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

            // Format contains the type of code i.e. UPC, EAN, QRCode etc...
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

            // Handle successful scan. In this example add contents to ArrayList
            results.add(contents);

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "PRODUCT_MODE,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0); // start the next scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User hass pressed 'back' instead of scanning. They are done.
            saveToCSV(results);
            //do whatever else you want.
        }
    }
}
```

Saving them to a CSV file is beyond the scope of this specific question, but If you look around you can find examples of how to do it. Consider it left blank as an exercise for you to learn from.

Comment: It exists as a setting inside the Android app, Barcode Scanner, but yes it is not exposed via Intent.

Comment: @SeanOwen Yup. But I saw there is an option to enable the Bulk scan mode. However, I can't seem to find any way to enable that unless I import the src codes into the program. Maybe in future there can be this Intent to do bulk scanning and return a list. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanOwen hope you see this. If I understand how the bulk scan mode works in the Barcode Scanner app - the camera preview is reset after certain delay?