# PhoneGap bulk barcode scan

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am researching into phonegap bulk barcode scanning,
I know about [com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner/tree/9270025f71891b2f46a38b7bc3d1223b4955dce2) and I know I could extend this plugin like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892461/how-to-trigger-bulk-mode-scan-in-zxing), but I was just wondering before I start doing that,
if there is already some solution so I don't waste my precious time.
(And yes I googled, didn't find anything)

What I actually want to achieve, I want that my application scanner is opened all the time(until user closes it) and doesn't need any confirmation or button clicking, so I can perform a bulk scan of lets say 50 barcodes and in the background the data in barcodes would asynchronously post to server or save in LocalStorage, doesn't matter where I just want the collection saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found another barcode scanning plugin it's called [Scandit](https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin) in my opinion its the fastest phonegap plugin out there it works really fast.

Since it did not have the multiple barcode support at the time I was implementing this I had to extend the code, this was a while ago so I hope that the patch still works you can find the patch [here](https://github.com/TheCodeDestroyer/usefull-files/tree/master/scandit)

Comment: Wasn't able to verify this since Scandit isn't free (anymore?).

Comment: You can try the trial

Comment: @TheCodeDestroyer the url of your patch is broken.

Comment: @FernandoKosh give me some time I'll try to find it somewhere it's been so long I probably deleted it

Comment: @FernandoKosh I created a repo and changed the url in my answer